# How to properly update build config / image stream when source code changes in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

((I'm still learning; apologize in advance if I may have misunderstood some basics.))

In OpenShift, I have a pipeline that uses *oc new-build (sourceCodeGitAddress)* and *oc start-build* to create my deployment. If I rerun the pipeline though, it fails because it says - rightfully so - that there is already a buildConfig and imageStream. Is there a better way for me to run this pipeline so it automatically updates / builds / pushes / etc. to the build config and image stream?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it. I think I just need a separate pipeline that just runs the **start-build** and it will re-pull the source code and deploy. At least, that's what I'm seeing in the logs. Please feel free to correct me!

Answer (score 0):

BuildConfig could be restarted via [webhook-triggers](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/triggering_builds.html#webhook-triggers) configuration or you have to exclude new-build operation from the pipeline.
In addition, 'oc apply' can be rerun idempotently
[More about BC start](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/basic_build_operations.html#starting-a-build)